# Run Firefox multiple times from different locations

Tags: firefox, proxy

I want to open 10 instances of Firefox (or another browser if not possible) with different proxies in each one of them. I have downloaded "Firefox Portable" and installed in a two different locations, but I can't open them up at the same time - I have used the command -no-remote-, but it doesn't work when Firefox is located in a different locations.

Is it possible to open Firefox multiple times while they are on different locations? if not, how can I run 10 instances of browser with different proxy on each?

Thanks.

Comment: A decent option would be to Shift and Right click and run as different user for each instance. All you would have to do is create 9 more users. If you dont want to clutter up your main system you could do this via Virtualbox or VMware.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it two ways.

First is explained below.

Open firefox portable and Rename the .exe to **firefox1**.exe

Do this for each instance.

So **firefox2.exe**, **firefox3.exe** and so on.

The path to the .exe is **\firefox\firefox 1\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox**

Then open them up and they will be under different processes.

Here is an example of two of portable version. Then you just set up a proxy for each.

[image]

The other way is to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd>

and select **Run as Different user**.

[image]

Of course you will need to set up multiple users for it to run for. Or use a virtual machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your #1 solution - it does open few instances, but all of them are the same as my main Firefox (same proxy, favorites etc). I have changed it here: http://take.ms/RacbM - Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I would try the different users then. You wouldnt need to keep them or log into them via desktop. Just make one and test it see if you can change the proxy settings which it should. If that does not work let me know and I can point you to another solution.